# Map function in "Haskell like" language using folr

Tags: functional-programming

I'm trying to write a `map` function in a [Haskell-like language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F#System_F%CF%89). The operation I'm trying to use is a `fold_right`. So basically writing a `map` using `foldr`. However, I get a "parameter mismatch error".

Thank you.

```
map = lambda X. lambda Y.
  lambda f: X -> Y.
    lambda l: List X.
      l [X] (
        lambda hd:X.
          lambda tl: List Y.
            (cons[Y](f hd))(tl)
      ) (nil [Y]);
```

Comment: Shouldn't be `Y` the return list type?

Comment: @Euge Can you please be more specific?

Comment: is the name of the language a huge secret, so you can't possibly name  it? give some links to related pages?

Comment: @WillNess it's called [System F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F#System_F%CF%89)

Comment: that's the description; but what's the implementation that gives you errors? A Wikipedia page can't do that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to `l` should be the type of the result of the fold (at least, that's my educated guess), the "motive". You want the end result to be a `List Y`, not an `X`, so you should say that:

```
map =
  lambda X. lambda Y. lambda f: X -> Y. lambda l: List X.
    l
      [List Y]
      (lambda x: X. lambda rec_xs: List Y. cons [Y] (f x) rec_xs)
      (nil [Y]);
```

Maybe you got confused and wrote `X` because `l` is a `List X`? `l` already knows that it contains `X`s; you don't need to point it out again. You just need to point out what you want get out (which *could* be `X`, but it isn't in this case).